# Tkinter: Resize window with ImageTk, Image, and Tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I have been trying to resize an image, but cannot figure out how to do it. Any help?

Here is the code:

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("someimage.png"))
img = img.resize((10, 10), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to resize the Image, not the PhotoImage.

```
original_img = Image.open("someimage.png")
resized_img = original_img.resize((10, 10), Image.ANTIALIAS)
photo_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_img)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked really well for me. How did you learn this? I tried everything!